# Use $addToSet (aggregate) to add objects to an array with one or more distinct properties

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
function findProfilesBySteamIds(ids, res) {
  var match = {
    $match: {
      $and : [
        { steamid: { $in : ids } }
      ]
    }
  }
  var sort = {
    $sort: {
      createdAt : -1
    }
  }
  var group = {
    $group: {
      _id : "$steamid",
      profile : { $first : "$$ROOT" },
      personahistory : { $push : "$$ROOT" }
    }
  }
  SteamUser
    .aggregate([match, sort, group])
}
```

Okay so here is my issue. I have a collection of profiles with a unique identifier `steamid`. I am grouping by `$steamid` and that functionality is working as expected. I also want to add a new field (not in the Schema) called `personahistory` that has an array of objects that is DISTINCT based on another property of the document, called `personaname`.

I have tried to use `$addToSet` following the mongoose reference docs but so far can only use it to create an array of that property only:

```
$group: {
  _id : "$steamid",
  profile : { $first : "$$ROOT" },
  personahistory : { $addToSet : "$personaname" }
}
```

This outputs:

```
{
   "_id": "1234567890",
   "profile": { ... },
   "personahistory" : [
     "personaname1",
     "personaname2",
     "personaname3"
   ]
}
```

Instead I'd like the output to be along the lines of:

```
{
   "_id": "1234567890",
   "profile": { ... },
   "personahistory" : [
     {
       "_id": "1234567890",
       "personaname": "personaname1",
       ...
     },
     {
       "_id": "1234567891",
       "personaname": "personaname2",
       ...
     },
     {
       "_id": "1234567892",
       "personaname": "personaname3",
       ...
     }
   ]
}
```

I've tried something like:

```
{ 
  $addToSet : { 
    "_id": "$steamid",
    "personaname": "$personaname"
  }
}
```

but to no avail.

Furthermore, if this behavior is even possible, I'd like to be able to use two or more DISTINCT fields. So, get all unique combinations of `personaname` and `avatarurl` and add those to the set.

Basically, I have a record each time the profile is queried but I only want to return records that are unique based on those two fields.

I'll be happy to provide more information if I haven't been clear enough.

Comment: it would be helpful if you add some examples of full documents and full expected results, not "short" examples like you added here (with the "..."). because you are looking for some kind of grouping, but what do you want to do with the rest of the fields that you are not grouping by them? it's unclear by the question.